# Range() function not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, built-in-types

I am trying to write the program that will be given a 2d list with coordinates of points on a grid (ex.`[[4, 7], [5, 6], [5, 2]]`), and will return all points passed during "walking". We can go diagonal.

```
def pole(lista):
    passed = []   #List with all points passed
    before = lista[0]  #list with coordinates before
    for i in range(1,len(lista)):
        first = [list(range(before[0],lista[i][0]))]   # Lists that should have all points
        second = [list(range(before[1],lista[i][1]))]  # passed from point to point

        if(len(first) == 1):                  #If we do not go diagonal, one list will only have one number here,
            first = [before[0]*len(second)]   # but we need the same number of itmes,
        if(len(second) == 1):                 # so we do not get IndexOutOFRange error in next for   
            second = [before[1]*len(first)]
        #print(first,second)
        for j in range(len(first)):
            passed.append([first[j], second[j]])
        before = lista[i]
    return passed
```

We are using the example list as an input. `[[4, 7], [5, 6], [5, 2]]`

The problem is that the output is wrong and I do not know why:

```
[[4, 7], [5, 6]]
```

And the output should be:

```
[[4,7], [5,6], [5,5], [5,4], [5,3], [5,2]]
```

I think it is a problem of range function

Comment: That is not the duplicate of that, why you marked my question as the duplicate?

Comment: Can you then please give us how you call the function, and what output you expected? I'm not clear as to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I may have acted too fast; the `[before[0]*len(second)]` call looks like you are multplying a nested list, like in the other canonical question.

Comment: For your example listed at the top of the question, I see `([4], [7])`, `([5], [6])`, `([5], [4])` printed, and `[[4, 7], [5, 6], [5, 4]]` returned.

Comment: Almost there, *what input do you give the function*, to produce the wrong output. I also don't understand what you are trying to do with the input.

Comment: `pole([[4, 7], [5, 6], [5, 2]])` produces `[[4, 7], [5, 6]]`, given the code in this question.

Comment: I've reopened the question, as the duplicate is incorrect. But your function is not producing the output you say it is.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the code while writing a question and did not checked if it changed something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think easiest way (presuming you've imported scipy) for going backwards is to say->
    for i in scipy.linspace(10,8,3)

Comment: What 3 means here? Is it step?

Answer (score 2):

That's because `range()` function does not count the last element.

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4]
>>> for i in range(len(x)):
    print (i)


0
1
2
3
>>>
```

You see, `4` is not here. You have to write `for i in range(len(something)+1)`.

Comment: Thanks, that solves a lot. But if I can not, becouse if it is, for example from 10 to 8 +1 is not correct.

Comment: @Krzys2014 from 10 to 8+1? You can't start from 10 if you going to 9. I don't understand what you mean

Comment: I meant that if range is from 10 to 8 the +1 won't work